# Selecting the maximum value from the results returned by NSolve

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

I'm trying to select the maximum value from the answers *Mathematica 7.0* is getting from a simple basic `NSolve` algebric equation :

```
rMax = Max[NSolve[20 == r (1 + 1/r)^2, r]]
```

I need the `rMax` value to be used in a simple graphic directive.

I'm unable to get it to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There ought to be an `r /.` in there somewhere…

Comment: I don't understand this.  Could you be more specific ?

Comment: Okay. Did you look at the examples under the docs for `NSolve[]`? Look for the ones using `/.`, and the ones not using it. Note the differences. After that, look up `ReplaceAll[]`.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing wrong is not paying attention to the form `NSolve` uses for returning results. Do it in three steps. First evaluate the your `NSolve` assigning the results to a variable. Do not end this assignment with a semicolon (;) -- you need to see the results. Next transform the results expression into a list of values. Finally apply `Max` to the list of values (I mean `Max @@ values`, not `Max[values]`.

```
results = NSolve[20 == r (1 + 1/r)^2, r]
```

> ```
> {{r -> 17.9443}, {r -> 0.0557281}}
> ```

```
values = results[[All, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {17.9443, 0.0557281}
> ```

```
Max @@ values
```

> ```
> 17.9443
> ```

Now that you see how it is done, you can put into one line with

```
rMax = Max @@ NSolve[20 == r (1 + 1/r)^2, r][[All, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> 17.9443
> ```

Comment: How should look a minimal code for doing this ?  I'm not sure to know how to apply your suggestion.

Comment: Wow !  Thanks a lot !  I'm learning new tricks each day !  8-)

Comment: Or `rMax=Max[r /. NSolve[20 == r (1 + 1/r)^2, r]]` also note that `Solve` could be used to get an exact solution: `rMax=Max[r /. Solve[20 == r (1 + 1/r)^2, r]]`

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks !  How do I get the second largest solution from this one ?

Comment: @Cham, a rather late reply, but: you use `RankedMax[]` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found another solution, a bit simpler and easier to understand (to a novice like me) :

Apparently, *Mathematica* output the results in **decreasing order**, so

```
results = NSolve[20 == r (1 + 1/r)^2, r][[All, 1, 2]]

rMin = results[[2]]
rMax = results[[1]]
```

Compiling this small code gives

```
{17.9443, 0.0557281}

0.0557281

17.9443
```

I found this solution more usefull for some third order equation with three roots, because the absolute smallest value (third solution) is always unphysical (too small).  The rMin I'm looking is actually the second root, not the third one.

Any opinion on this solution to my first question ?

Comment: I would not depend on the `NSolve` solution ordering. Especially if there are complex-valued solutions.